# Playing music using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to play music, such as "do", "re", "me" using C# without using any other files on my computer? I have been searching online for ages and all of them are importing files from their computer Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play a sound of a specified frequency and duration using `Console.Beep`.

MSDN:

> `Beep(Int32, Int32)` 
> Plays the sound of a beep of a specified frequency and duration through the console speaker. *[More...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-5.0#System_Console_Beep_System_Int32_System_Int32_)*

e.g.:

```
Console.Beep (247,  // the note "B"
              800); // half-note
```

The values used in the above example can be found explained along with others in the example found in the link below.

### More

- *[Beep(Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-5.0#System_Console_Beep_System_Int32_System_Int32_)*

Comment: @kimilao not a problem